# After changing a variable in django need to restart the server to update the variable

Tags: python, html, django

I'm a beginner in python and django and learned how to send data to the template, but if I'm trying to change the data (variable) while the server is running and reload the page, the data remains old, and to fix that I need to restart the server. Am I missing something?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    context = {
        'name': 'Nick',
        'age': 24
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
<h1>Hi, {{name}}<br>You are {{age}} years old</h1>
```

Comment: Are you running the development server - `python manage.py runserver`? You haven't enabled the per-site cache have you? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache

Comment: I didn't, but even after enabling still the same result

Comment: Can you see the logs from the dev server? Does it restart when you change one of your Python files?

Comment: I don't know how, but I guess it doesn't and that can be the reason for the problem